# Inconsistent MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

The following PHP code works perfectly:

```
<?php 
// AJAX check for email availability (against database)
if(isset($_POST["email"])){
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($check < 1){
        echo '1';
        exit();
    }else{
        echo '0';
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

But I ended up needing this bit of code a couple times, so I took it and put it into a function:

```
<?php
function checkE($email){
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($check < 1){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
?>
```

The first bit of code works flawlessly every time, but the second function only returns "1", that is to say that it never finds a match in the database (or `$check` is always less than 1), even when comparing an email that would otherwise be caught by the first bit of code.

I've tried echoing out `$check` from the second function, and it only prints out a blank space. The codes are essentially identical, save the assignment of `$email` in the first bit.

Am I just tired and missing something obvious in the function?

And if needed:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name);
```

Comment: `$dbc` variable is undefined in scope of `checkE` function

Comment: Its illogical to say: if its less then 1, return 1, instead say: if its less then 1, return 0, since less then 1 is 0. but that aside, how are you calling your function?, is the email parameter set right in your function call?

Comment: Please use prepared statements. Sending POST variables to the database like that will get you hacked.

Comment: @u_mulder I put `$dbc` within the function, and still no change.

Comment: @KoenHoeijmakers yes, I've echoed out the `$email` being passed to the function, it is correct.

Comment: Edit the question to show how you put it and show how you call the function.

Comment: check print_r($check)..and use this {$email} instead of this '$email'

Comment: You can put $dbc in the function, but then $db_host and the other parameters are out of scope. Point is, any variable from outside the function either needs to be passed as an argument, or you can put it in scope using the `global` keyword (but only if it is indeed a global variable).

Comment: @u_mulder sorry yeah you're right, it's working now. All I needed to do was modify the function call to `checkE($email, $dbc)` and it worked out. Thank you!

Comment: It's not entirely your fault. The [PHP documentation about functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) seems to lack every bit of information about scope.

Comment: @idstam I will be using prepared statements. This is just a proof of concept and a little bit quicker/easier for me to write. Thank you for the heads up though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add $dbc to your function parameters like this:

```
function checkE($email,$dbc){
```

Then call your function like this:

```
checkE('horse@horseman.horse',$dbc);
```

You're not passing the $dbc variable right now.

Comment: Just adding so the question isn't "unanswered"